# Intellij: Tomcat 8 memory leak

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on `IntelliJ 15` and running a couple of `tomcat 8` servers.
My problem is whatever webapp I'm deploying, the tomcat occupies at least 700M.

Question: How can I optimize the Tomcat running instance in IntelliJ ? Is it a known problem ?

(When I was working on Eclipse, I didn't have much memory leak).